# How to animate only checked checbox in listview

Tags: android

I want to animate checkbox so am using below code

```
public class CircleCheckBox extends View {
private float innerCircleRadius = 19.f;
private float outerCircleRadius = innerCircleRadius / 2f;
private float textSize = 0f;
private float borderThickness = 5f;
private float tickThickness = 2f;
private float textLeftPadding = 2f;

private float increment = 20;
private float total_time = 200;
private final Paint mPaintPageFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint mPaintPageStroke = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint mPaintTick = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint mPaintOuter = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private final Paint mPaintText = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private boolean firstRun = true;
private boolean timer_running = false;
private float tick_third_ = innerCircleRadius / 3;
private boolean draw_tick_part_one = false;
private String text = "";

private int tick_color = Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
private int text_color = Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0);
private int outerCircleColor = Color.argb(100, 0, 207, 173);
private int innerCircleColor = Color.argb(255, 0, 207, 173);
private int circleBorderColor = Color.argb(255, 0, 207, 173);

private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;

private boolean showOuterCircle = true;

float centerX = 0;
float centerY = 0;
public boolean isChecked = false;

private boolean draw_tick = false;

Timer timer = new Timer();

public CircleCheckBox(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public CircleCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public CircleCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CircleCheckbox,
                0, 0);

        try {
            setTickColorHex(a.getString(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_tickColor));
            setTextColorHex(a.getString(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_textColor));
            setShowOuterCircle(a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_showOuterCircle, true));
            setInnerCircleColorHex(a.getString(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_innerCircleColor));
            setOuterCircleColorHex(a.getString(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_outerCircleColor));
            setCircleBorderColorHex(a.getString(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_circleBorderColor));
            setTickThickness(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_tickThickness, tickThickness));
            setBorderThickness(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_borderThickness, borderThickness));
            setTextLeftPadding(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_textLeftPadding, textLeftPadding));
            setTextSize(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_textSize, textSize));
            setInnerCircleRadius(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_innerCircleRadius, innerCircleRadius));
            setOuterCircleRadius(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_outerCircleRadius, outerCircleRadius));
            setText(a.getString(R.styleable.CircleCheckbox_text));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    mPaintOuter.setColor(outerCircleColor);
    mPaintPageFill.setColor(innerCircleColor);
    mPaintTick.setColor(tick_color);
    mPaintTick.setStrokeWidth(tickThickness * 2);

    mPaintPageStroke.setColor(circleBorderColor);
    mPaintPageStroke.setStrokeWidth(borderThickness);
    mPaintPageStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    mPaintText.setTextSize(textSize);
    mPaintText.setColor(text_color);

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setChecked(!isChecked);
        }
    });
}

private float current_radius = 0.0f;
float time = 0;

float tick_x = 0;
float tick_y = 0;
float tick_x_two = 0;
float tick_y_two = 0;
float inc_tick = 0;
// Interpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (centerX == 0) {
        centerX = innerCircleRadius + outerCircleRadius + getPaddingLeft();
    }
    centerY = getHeight() / 2;

    //float interpolation = Math.abs(interpolator.getInterpolation(time));

    float inc = innerCircleRadius / (total_time / increment);

    float time_inc = 1 / (total_time / increment);
    time += time_inc;

    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, innerCircleRadius, mPaintPageStroke);

    if (isChecked) {
        if (draw_tick) {
            float tick_offset = tickThickness * 2;
            if (showOuterCircle) {
                canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, current_radius + outerCircleRadius, mPaintOuter);
            }
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, innerCircleRadius, mPaintPageFill);
            if (draw_tick_part_one) {
                inc_tick = tick_third_ / (total_time / increment);

                tick_x += inc_tick;
                tick_y += inc_tick;
                canvas.drawCircle(centerX - tick_offset - tick_third_, centerY, tickThickness, mPaintTick);
                canvas.drawLine(centerX - tick_offset - tick_third_, centerY, tick_x - tick_offset, tick_y, mPaintTick);
                canvas.drawCircle(tick_x - tick_offset, tick_y, tickThickness, mPaintTick);
            } else {
                canvas.drawCircle(centerX - tick_offset - tick_third_, centerY, tickThickness, mPaintTick);
                canvas.drawLine(centerX - tick_offset - tick_third_, centerY, tick_x - tick_offset, tick_y, mPaintTick);
                canvas.drawCircle(tick_x - tick_offset, tick_y, tickThickness, mPaintTick);

                inc_tick = tick_third_ * 1.7f / (total_time / increment);

                tick_x_two += inc_tick;
                tick_y_two -= inc_tick;

                canvas.drawLine(centerX - tick_offset, tick_y, tick_x_two - tick_offset, tick_y_two, mPaintTick);
                canvas.drawCircle(tick_x_two - tick_offset, tick_y_two, tickThickness, mPaintTick);
            }

        } else {
            current_radius = current_radius + inc;

            if (showOuterCircle && current_radius >= innerCircleRadius - outerCircleRadius) {
                canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, (current_radius + outerCircleRadius), mPaintOuter);
            }
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, current_radius, mPaintPageFill);
        }
    } else {
        if (!firstRun) {

            current_radius = current_radius - inc;
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, current_radius, mPaintPageFill);
        }
    }

    if (isChecked) {
        if (!timer_running) {
            tick_x = centerX;// tick_third_;
            tick_y = centerY + tick_third_;
            float tick_offset = tickThickness * 2;
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX - tick_offset - tick_third_, centerY, tickThickness, mPaintTick);
            canvas.drawLine(centerX - tick_offset - tick_third_, centerY, tick_x - tick_offset, tick_y, mPaintTick);
            canvas.drawCircle(tick_x - tick_offset, tick_y, tickThickness, mPaintTick);

            tick_x_two = tick_x + (tick_third_ * 1.7f);
            tick_y_two = tick_y - (tick_third_ * 1.7f);
            canvas.drawLine(centerX - tick_offset, tick_y, tick_x_two - tick_offset, tick_y_two, mPaintTick);
            canvas.drawCircle(tick_x_two - tick_offset, tick_y_two, tickThickness, mPaintTick);
            tick_x = 0;
            tick_y = 0;
            tick_x_two = 0;
            tick_x_two = 0;

            current_radius = innerCircleRadius;
        }
    }

    canvas.drawText(text, centerX + textLeftPadding + innerCircleRadius + outerCircleRadius, centerY + textSize / 2, mPaintText);
    firstRun = false;
}

private void startAnimationTimer() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        int time = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer_running = true;
            time += increment;
            if (time <= total_time) {
                postInvalidate();
            } else {
                if (isChecked) {
                    startTickAnimation();
                } else {
                    timer_running = false;
                }
                cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, (int) increment);
}

private void startTickAnimation() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        int time = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw_tick_part_one = true;
            timer_running = true;
            draw_tick = true;
            if (time == 0) {
                tick_x = centerX - tick_third_;
                tick_y = centerY;
            }

            time += increment;
            if (time <= total_time) {
                postInvalidate();
            } else {
                draw_tick_part_one = false;
                startTickPartTwoAnimation();
                cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, (int) increment);
}

private void startTickPartTwoAnimation() {

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        int time = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer_running = true;
            draw_tick = true;
            if (time == 0) {
                tick_x_two = tick_x;
                tick_y_two = tick_y;
            }

            time += increment;
            if (time <= total_time) {
                postInvalidate();
            } else {
                timer_running = false;
                draw_tick = false;
                cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, (int) increment);
}

public int getTickColor() {
    return tick_color;
}

public void setTickColor(int tick_color) {
    this.tick_color = tick_color;
}

public void setTickColorHex(String tick_color) {
    if (tick_color != null)
        this.tick_color = Color.parseColor(tick_color);
}

public int getTextColor() {
    return text_color;
}

public void setTextColor(int text_color) {
    this.text_color = text_color;
}

public void setTextColorHex(String color) {
    if (color != null)
        this.text_color = Color.parseColor(color);
}

public boolean isShowOuterCircle() {
    return showOuterCircle;
}

public void setShowOuterCircle(boolean showOuterCircle) {
    this.showOuterCircle = showOuterCircle;
}

public int getInnerCircleColor() {
    return innerCircleColor;
}

public void setInnerCircleColor(int innerCircleColor) {
    this.innerCircleColor = innerCircleColor;
}

public void setInnerCircleColorHex(String innerCircleColor) {
    if (innerCircleColor != null)
        this.innerCircleColor = Color.parseColor(innerCircleColor);
}

public int getOuterCircleColor() {
    return outerCircleColor;
}

public void setOuterCircleColor(int outerCircleColor) {
    this.outerCircleColor = outerCircleColor;
}

public void setOuterCircleColorHex(String outerCircleColor) {
    if (outerCircleColor != null)
        this.outerCircleColor = Color.parseColor(outerCircleColor);
}

public int getCircleBorderColor() {
    return circleBorderColor;
}

public void setCircleBorderColor(int circleBorderColor) {
    this.circleBorderColor = circleBorderColor;
}

public void setCircleBorderColorHex(String color) {
    if (color != null)
        this.circleBorderColor = Color.parseColor(color);
}

public float getTickThickness() {
    return tickThickness;
}

public void setTickThickness(float tickThickness) {
    this.tickThickness = tickThickness;
}

public float getBorderThickness() {
    return borderThickness;
}

public void setBorderThickness(float borderThickness) {
    this.borderThickness = borderThickness;
}

public float getTextLeftPadding() {
    return textLeftPadding;
}

public void setTextLeftPadding(float textLeftPadding) {
    this.textLeftPadding = textLeftPadding;
}

public float getTextSize() {
    return textSize;
}

public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
    this.textSize = textSize;
}

public float getInnerCircleRadius() {
    return innerCircleRadius;
}

public void setInnerCircleRadius(float innerCircleRadius) {
    this.innerCircleRadius = innerCircleRadius;
}

public float getOuterCircleRadius() {
    return outerCircleRadius;
}

public void setOuterCircleRadius(float outerCircleRadius) {
    this.outerCircleRadius = outerCircleRadius;
}

public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {

    if (!timer_running) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onCheckedChanged(this, isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            current_radius = 0;
            inc_tick = 0;
        }
        time = 0;
        startAnimationTimer();
    }
}



public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    void onCheckedChanged(CircleCheckBox view, boolean isChecked);
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    if (text != null) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

}
The checkbox is in listview and `checkbox.setChecked(true)`
is in onItemClick listner of listview. But the problem is when i clicked on item all checkbox are animating. i want to animate only the which i clicked.